# Installing wordpress on subdirectory 2 levels down

Tags: htaccess, navigation, 404-error, directory, hosting

An unusual one for you and I appreciate how ridiculous this set up sounds but It's currently what I've got to work with so here we go...

I have a joomla website set up on www.myjoomlasite.com. I am attempting to add a Wordpress Blog to a subdirectory of www.joomlasite.com, more specifically www.joomlasite.com/jack/blog

So as you can see I've gone 2 levels down. I'm wondering what I have to do in order to achieve this as currently I am getting a few issues.

I've gotten the Wordpress site set up within the/jack/blog directory and the home page displays fine. However when I click a link in the navigation I get a 404 error from the Joomla site. I'm guessing it's something to do with my .htaccess file but I really am not sure!

I updated the siteurl and the home fields in the wp_options table to http://www.myjoomlasite.com/jack/blog but the links are still not working.

Would any one be able to advise me on what could be going wrong...

Many  thanks in advance, and again I know it sounds crazy having a joomla site and putting a wordpress blog on top of it but It's just the nature of this particular situation.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this myself. Apologies for wasting anyones time. The fix was simple. I just had to add the following piece of code to my `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /jack/blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /jack/blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Save my permalinks and the problem was solved. As I guessed it was a .htaccess issue and something I stupidly overlooked. Hope this helps anyone with the same issues as me.
Thanks